# Notes Registration function is pass or fail validation using lotus script agent

Tags: wsdl, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I using web service call lotus notes agent. Now i can't really tell whether the application is pass or fail during calling agent. is it possible to check reregistration is pass or fail using **lotus script agent**.

```
Dim reg As New NotesRegistration
```

My question is during notes registration if fail, is it possible to be check? as let say my application do on 2 server.

1. work server = worksvr/names.nsf.
2. Mail server = mailsvr/  , mail\person

My mail server offline, make the registration failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each web service can return a value to the caller. So you execute the registration and based on the result return that status to the caller. A simple check, before you execute all that code: check if you can open that server's names.nsf. If not -> fail, If yes -> continue

To avoid hardcoding use a policy for registration. AFAIK you can specify to defer the mail file creation there, which makes your script more resilient.